# Paypal PayFlow pro Response always Fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal-sandbox

I  need to integrate paypal payflow payment in my website. I  have Used [this Library](https://www.angelleye.com/codeigniter-paypal-integration-tutorial/).

My sample paypal pay flow  sample response, Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [RESULT] => 0
    [PNREF] => A30A2C9B2AD0
    [RESPMSG] => Approved
    [AUTHCODE] => 785PNI
    [AVSADDR] => Y
    [AVSZIP] => Y
    [CVV2MATCH] => Y
    [HOSTCODE] => A
    [PROCAVS] => Y
    [PROCCVV2] => M
    [VISACARDLEVEL] => 12
    [TRANSTIME] => 2018-01-22 03:51:49
    [BILLTOFIRSTNAME] => Tester
    [BILLTOLASTNAME] => Testerson
    [AMT] => 10.50
    [ACCT] => 1111
    [EXPDATE] => 1219
    [CARDTYPE] => 0
    [IAVS] => N
    [PREFPSMSG] => No Rules Triggered
    [POSTFPSMSG] => No Rules Triggered
    [RAWREQUEST] => BUTTONSOURCE[18]=Paypal Transaction&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH&USER[8]=aswinraj&VENDOR[11]=Vigneshwari&PARTNER[6]=Paypal&PWD[13]=vickyaswin@13&TENDER[1]=C&TRXTYPE[1]=S&ACCT[16]=4111111111111111&EXPDATE[4]=1219&AMT[5]=10.50&FREIGHTAMT[4]=5.00&TAXAMT[4]=2.50&COMMENT1[15]=This is a test!&COMMENT2[20]=This is only a test!&CVV2[3]=123&BILLTOEMAIL[22]=sandbox@testdomain.com&BILLTOPHONENUM[12]=816-555-5555&BILLTOFIRSTNAME[6]=Tester&BILLTOLASTNAME[9]=Testerson&BILLTOSTREET[13]=123 Test Ave.&BILLTOCITY[6]=TUCSON&BILLTOSTATE[2]=AZ&BILLTOZIP[9]=123456789&BILLTOCOUNTRY[3]=USA&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME[6]=Tester&SHIPTOLASTNAME[9]=Testerson&SHIPTOSTREET[13]=123 Test Ave.&SHIPTOCITY[6]=TUCSON&SHIPTOSTATE[2]=AZ&SHIPTOZIP[9]=123456789&SHIPTOCOUNTRY[3]=USA
    [RAWRESPONSE] => RESULT=0&PNREF=A30A2C9B2AD0&RESPMSG=Approved&AUTHCODE=785PNI&AVSADDR=Y&AVSZIP=Y&CVV2MATCH=Y&HOSTCODE=A&PROCAVS=Y&PROCCVV2=M&VISACARDLEVEL=12&TRANSTIME=2018-01-22 03:51:49&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Tester&BILLTOLASTNAME=Testerson&AMT=10.50&ACCT=1111&EXPDATE=1219&CARDTYPE=0&IAVS=N&PREFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered&POSTFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered
)
```

I have got only RESULT column  as 0 and RESPMSG as approved in error response . But I need  success Response .Please help me to fix the issue .

Answer (score 0):

If Payflow API responds as **RESTULT=0** & **RESPMSG=approved**, it means transaction has been completed without any error.

[Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#transaction-responses) to know about Payflow API response.

[Click here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/result_values_for_transaction_declines_or_errors.htm)  to know more about RESPMSG with its explanation.